# Proper Use of Redux-Ovservable ajax http methods: put, delete, post

Tags: rxjs5, redux-observable

I'm new to Redux and Redux-Observable.  I'm having success in getting information from a rest API with GET and GET(ID), but I cannot get the Delete and Post to work.  Sample code below that is issuing a GET request:

```
[EPIC File]
import { debounceTime, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax';
import ActionTypes from '../actions/ActionTypes';
import { receiveFeedBack, receiveDeleteFeedBackId,
receiveFeedBackId } from '../actions/FeedBackActions';


export const fetchFeedBack = (action$) =>      ... Working
export const fetchFeedBackId  = (action$) =>   ... Working

//Not Working
export const deleteFeedBackById = (action$) =>
  action$.ofType(ActionTypes.DELETE_FEEDBACK_REQUEST)
  .debounceTime(500)
  .switchMap(action =>
    ajax.delete(`${ActionTypes
      .FEEDBACK__URL}/posts/${action.payload.feedbackId}?key=${ActionTypes
      .FEEDBACK__API_KEY}`)
      .map(receiveDeleteFeedBackId.bind(action))
      .takeUntil(action$.ofType(ActionTypes.DELETE_FEEDBACK_CANCELED))
      .catch(error => Observable.of({
        type: ActionTypes.DELETE_FEEDBACK_ERROR,
        payload: error
      }))
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you're saying `ajax.delete(...)` makes a _GET_ requests, instead of a _DELETE_? Can you describe what happens? Do you get an error? What error?

Comment: Is this trying to make it cross-domain? Do you receive any CORS errors in the console?

Comment: Thank you jayhelps, it seems your simple comments made me look at my code again.  Actually for the second day!.  It turns out that I forgot to add the "deleteFeedBackById" method to the "combineEpics" file. Sharing: I had this working with redux-promise, then I changed to redux-thunk for async.  Realizing I need additional features like cancel request, I searched the web, found your's and Ben's AWESOME video and have begun the conversion to redux-observables.  So, thank you for your quick feedback and many thanks for the video.

Comment: ah got it, so it wasn't doing anything cause it wasn't included in the root epic so it never runs. Cheers!

Comment: Exactly. Again,thanks for this "Most Excellent" product.  For me, its is a "Must Have" package for any Redux Enabled App.